# How to load css with ocLazyLoad in Angular?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to use ocLazyLoad to load new css files when I change states with ui-router in a MEAN application.

The problem is that when I change from A to B state, all styles from A remains in B plus the B CSS loaded by ocLazyLoad. I want that when I change from A to B my app remove all CSS loaded by A but not the ones that were loaded in the template.

Template:

1. example.css

A:

1. example.css (loaded by Template)
2. a.css (loaded by ocLazyLoad)

A to B:

1. example.css (loaded by Template)
2. <del>a.css (Remains from A loaded y ocLazyLoad)</del> *(I want to remove this automatically)*
3. b.css (loaded by ocLazyLoad)

This is what I'm doiapp.js:

```
testApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ocLazyLoadProvider) {

    $ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
        debug: true
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("A");

    $stateProvider

        .state('a', {
        url: '/a',
        templateUrl: '../views/a.html',
        resolve: {
            deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load([{
                    name: 'testApp',
                    files: [                     
                        'css/a.css'
                    ]
                }]);
            }]
        }
    })

    .state('b', {
        url: '/b',
        templateUrl: '../views/b.html',
        resolve: {
            deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load([{
                    name: 'testApp',
                    files: [
                        'css/b.css'
                    ]
                }]);
            }]
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Why do you want to remove it? If a user goes back to A they have to load it again?

Comment: @Starscream1984 yep, because some styles are being replaced

Comment: You could just make your css more specific - set a class like `page-a` on your template root element and put `.page-a` before all the rules on `a.css`. Then those style will not affect anything on page `b`